# MongoDB Atlas initial high number of connections and storage

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I just created a new empty cluster on mongoDB atlas. I chose the M20 cluster tier with 60GB storage limit. However, as soon as my cluster was created, it showed that there are 28 current connections on the server hosting the replica set (keeps increasing and decreasing, even reached 35). It also shows that the current disk space used is 6.3GB even though the cluster was just created and empty.

Is this normal on Atlas? And why is the number this high? This bugs me as there is a limit on the number of connections and storage.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are connections from:

- Each node in RS to other nodes
- Atlas backup & management software

Disk use goes toward:

- Preallocated data & log files (per node)

Some connections and some disk use is to be expected. If you wish to have more information as to what the connections are used for and where the disk space goes, you could use the official Atlas support channels to inquire.