# Can I reuse an connection in mongodb? How this connections actually work?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Trying to do some simple things with mongodb my mind got stuck in something that feels kinda strange for me.

```
client = MongoClient(connection_string)
db = client.database
    
print(db)
    
client.close()
```

I thought that when make a connection it is used only this one along the rest of the code until the close() method. But it doesn't seem to work that way... I don't know how I ended up having 9 connections when it supposed to be a single one, and even if each 'request' is a connection there's too many of them

[image: connection status]

For now it's not a big problem, just bothers me the fact that I don't know exactly how this works!

Comment: What is the picture of?

Comment: Its a print from the metrics section of the cluster i'm using

Comment: So server connection count?

Comment: I really have no clue on how this works, but executed the code two more times and it didnt showed up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB Atlas initial high number of connections and storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838440/mongodb-atlas-initial-high-number-of-connections-and-storage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `new MongoClient()`, you are not establishing just one connection. In fact you are creating the client, that will have a connection pool. When you do one or multiple requests, the driver uses an available connection from the pool. When the use is complete, the connection goes back to the pool.

Calling MongoClient constructor every time you need to talk to the db is a very bad practice and will incur a penalty for the handshake. Use dependency injection or singleton to have MongoClient.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo), you should create one client per process.

Your code seems to be the correct way *if it is a single thread* process. If you don't need any more connections to the server, you can limit the pool size by explicitly specifying the number:

`client = MongoClient(host, port, maxPoolSize=<num>)`.

On the other hand, if the code might later use the same connection, it is better to simply create the client once in the beginning, and use it across the code.